# How to subract data in line1 from line2 from line3 etc in shell script ?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with one column and many lines.

I want to subtract each line from one another so as to check for which of the lines i am expected to start having a constant difference.

```
i.e
line1-line2
line2-line3
line3-line4
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do so:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print prev - $1} {prev=$1}' <input_file>
```

This way, the action `{print  prev - $1}` is executed only for lines after the first one, while the action `{prev=$1}` is executed for every line, but after the first pattern has been evaluated and is corresponding action, in case, performed.

Comment: *line1-line2*! : `{print prev - $1}` !?

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop. Remember the last line read:

```
previous=0
while read n ; do
    if ((previous)) ; then
        echo $((previous-n))
    fi
    previous=$n
done
```

If your lines contain floats, use `bc` or switch to some scripting language like Perl.